# Тип timestamp отображается как DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

Установил в таблице тестовой тип поля `timestamp`, и при добавлении туда значения в виде `1421312123` оно отображается как `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Почему так происходит?

Перепроверяю, тип действительно `timestamp`.

Comment: А что по вашему должно быть?
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

тип [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) хранит дату и время (отметку времени):

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

---

вы же пытаетесь вставить в столбец число (в математическом смысле этого слова).

это число весьма похоже на количество секунд, прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:01` по `2015-01-15 11:55:23` (в московском часовом поясе), т.е., на [*unix-время* (*unix timestamp*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

если так, то нужно преобразовать это число в дату и время с помощью функции [`from_unixtime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). примерно так:

```
insert into t values (from_unixtime(1421312123));
```

тогда в столбец с типом `timestamp` попадёт корректное значение, и эта отметка времени будет корректно отображаться:

```
select * from t;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2015-01-15 11:55:23 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Извините, почему он отображается как в формате `DATETIME`, то есть в формате `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, а не числами, так было всегда или же я что-то путаю. Спасибо

Comment: физически тип `timestamp` хранит количество секунд с начала т.н. [unix-эпохи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F). а отображать можно по-разному (см. [функции `time_format()`, `date_format()`, `from_unixtime()` и т.п.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)). выбор умолчального формата отображения объясняют так: [The TIMESTAMP syntax produces a DATETIME value in MySQL because DATETIME has a range that more closely corresponds to the standard SQL TIMESTAMP type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: по умолчанию при `SELECT column_timestamp FROM table` тут колонка `column_timestamp` timestamp, что должно выходить?